# NetBeans android

Tags: android, netbeans

I've a problem with nbandroid this is what i get when i want to clean build, or run my project.

First : I've got : package `R` does not exist.

I tried the solution given in : http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/NetBeans for the R package

> /home/blop/Android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt: error
>   while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory
>
> /home/blop/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:647: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> /home/blop/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:688: null
>   returned: 127

BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: What did you try exactly? Did you add in the lines to the build.xml?

Comment: Ok, I know this won't fix your issues but why don't you use eclipse or better IntelliJ IDEA for android development? It would be much easier because it have support for android..

Comment: I don't want to use plenty tools I already use Netbeans for Drupal/PHP/.. for Java/Java EE, C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

I also use nbandroid and netbeans. There are several things you can try.

1 - Make sure that the sdk is set tools -> options -> misc -> android -> SDK Location. I have seen many times that nbandroid or netbeans loses the location path and this might cause problems.

2 - Check that the file "local.properties", in your project folder contains the correct SDK location. Sometimes, when you work on different workstations, it still has the sdk location from the previous build/workstation.

3 - Make sure that all your classes contains the package line at the top, e.g.

package you.android.app.package;

4 - If it still does not work, make sure that you are not importing the android.R package, as that will look in there for your files instead of your project.

That's usually how I fix it if I encounter that problem, hope it works for you.

P.s. there's nothing wrong with using netbeans. I have used both netbeans and eclipse and have had a better experience with netbeans and the git integration. Also, nbandroid now comes with a layout preview which is pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like NBAndroid problem. More likely you cannot run Android SDK tools namely aapt. It is 32-bit executable on my system and also the SDK web says: 64-bit distributions must be capable of running 32-bit applications. Install ia32-libs (and ia32-libs-gtk maybe) package and check again.